# Can Support undo the (not yet released) deletion of a managed field?

Tags: managed-package, isv, deprecation, salesforce-support

The `CustomChild`__c object was tied to `CustomParent`__c using a mdr_`BadlyNamed`__c relation. I planned on replacing it with a better named field and knew that this meant some migration on each customer org.

But after I deleted mdr_`BadlyNamed`__c in my packaging org I was shocked to learn that I cannot create another MDR on this object.

I could also not find a way to undelete the old file.

Am I screwed (and my customers how use this child object)? Or will Salesforce support be able to help undo not yet released deletions?

Comment: I would "think" that they should be able to but the only way to know for sure is to open a support ticket.....The bigger issue is the fact that you cannot create a new MDR. They should either fix that or not allow the deletion of the MDR. Either way a ticket will need to be created

Comment: Have you checked `The component can be deleted, but can only be undeleted from the Deleted Package Components page` and the details here https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=viewing_deleted_components.htm&language=en_US - Seems to state it will work as long as you have not uploaded the package.

Comment: @Eric Also I did NOT Upload anything I was unable to restore the deleted file from neigther the Recycle bin nor the Deleted Components page :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No they can't!**

Tier 3 support just replied to my case. We really have "lost" a packaged object (installed in many customer orgs) to the database "nirvana". And have to create a new one including a migration works.

BUT, yes we have been warned:

[image]